# Spring Boot ошибка Error creating bean with name 'ControllerName'

Tags: java, tomcat, rest, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

Пробую делать REST сервис на Spring Boot. Возвращаемые данные в Json.
При запуске приложения получаю ошибку:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'messageController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'messageService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageService' defined in file
>   [D:\JavaProgramming\JavaTraning\SpringREST\target\classes\com\sttech\springrest\service\MessageService.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.sttech.springrest.service.MessageService]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Сервер Tomcat.
**Application**

```
package com.sttech.springrest;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Контроллер **MessageController**

```
package com.sttech.springrest.api;
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/api/messages") //http://localhost:8080/api/messages
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @RequestMapping
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }
}
```

**MessageService**

```
package com.sttech.springrest.service;
@Service
public class MessageService {

    private static Map<Long, Message> messages;

    public MessageService() {
        messages.put(1L, new Message(1, "Hello World", "ABC"));
        messages.put(2L, new Message(2, "Hello Jersey", "QWE"));
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {

        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    }
}
```

**Message** и конструктор:

```
package com.sttech.springrest.model;
public class Message {

  private long id;
  private String message;
  private Date created;
  private String author;

  public Message() {
  }

  public Message(long id, String message, String author) {
    this.id = id;
    this.message = message;
    this.author = author;
    this.created = new Date();
  }
+ getters/setters.
```

Comment: А `http://localhost:8084/api/messages` тоже не работает?

Comment: http://localhost:8084/ работает. http://localhost:8084/api/messages дает 404.

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш контроллер зарегистрирован в контексте?

Comment: Не могли бы этот момент поподробнее, я только изучаю spring.

Comment: При старте приложение пишет какие маппинги зарегистрированы. Посмотрите вывод на консоль, там должен быть маппинг для `/api/messages`.

Comment: Да, у меня не было файла Application. Создал его запустил пустой проект, Tomcat запустился, получил сообщение что не настроен маппинг. Добавил свои классы в проект, запустил в логе получаю ошибки:

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageController' defined in file [path/MessageController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sttech.springrest.api.MessageController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: А что у вас в конструкторе `MessageController`? Ну и создавать `MessageService` через new тоже неправильно, надо создавать его как бин и инжектить в контроллер.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin Добавил в вопрос класс Message. С бинами и инжектами пока не разобрался.

Comment: Интересовал MessageController, не Message :)

Comment: MessageController весь наверху кроме импортов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы не инициализируете поле `MessageService.messages`, поэтому оно у вас `null`. И весьма плохая практика заполнять статическое поле в конструкторе - либо заполняйте в статическом инициализаторе (`static { ... }`), либо сделайте поле нестатическим. Итого:

```
private Map<Long, Message> messages = new HashMap<>();
```